# How to get the previous value of record related field in validation rule?

Tags: validation, field-update, automation, update

I have a requirement to create a validation rule to check if the profile of the Case owner is same with the profile of the new case owner. If yes, allow to update the case owner. How can I achieve this using validation rule? I could not get the profile Id of the case owner before change.

```
IF( Owner:User.ProfileId <> PRIORVALUE(Owner:User.ProfileId) 
    true,
    false

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved with a validation rule.

There may be a way to use a flow to bring this information into a dedicated field on `Case`, but I think that this is something more suited for a Trigger (in which you could use SObject's `.addError()` to prevent the record save from completing).